# Lisp : Don't know how to create ISeq from Java.lang.Integer

Tags: java, clojure, lisp

I'm trying to open a text file and split it into a list of integer values in Clojure. I get this error code every single time, and I've got no idea why. I'm relatively new to Lisp development (I mean I started like two hours ago), so it might be that I'm asking a really silly question. Cheers

```
(ns clojure.examples.hello
  (:gen-class))

(ns clojure-noob.core)

(defn toInt [s]
  (Integer/parseInt (re-find #"\A-?\d+" s)))
(defn toIntList [s]
  (if (not s) ()
    (list* (toInt (first (toInt s)) (toIntList first((rest 
  (clojure.string/split s #" "))))))
  )
)

(println (str (toIntList (slurp "hab.txt"))))
```

Comment: Could you post a sample input like what `hab.txt` would contain?

Comment: just a bunch of integers separated by spaces

Answer (score 3):

The reason you are getting that error message is that (somewhere) you are incorrectly calling a function that expects a sequence argument with an integer argument. One place that this could be is here:

```
(first (toInt s))
```

The function `first` expects a sequence (`ISeq`), yet `toInt` is returning an integer.

And just to confirm:

```
(first (java.lang.Integer/parseInt "10"))
```

> IllegalArgumentException Don't know how to create ISeq from: java.lang.Integer

Answer (score 1):

Assuming `hab.txt` is just a single line of space-delimited integers, this should work:

```
(defn to-int [s]
  (Integer/parseInt (re-find #"\A-?\d+" s)))
(defn parse-int-str [s]
  (map to-int (clojure.string/split s #" ")))
(println (parse-int-str "1 2 3 4 5"))
=> (1 2 3 4 5)
```

Or a recursive version as requested:

```
(defn parse-int-str [s]
  (loop [nums []
         strs (clojure.string/split s #" ")]
    (if (seq strs)
      (recur (conj nums (to-int (first strs)))
             (rest strs))
      nums)))
```

You could do this without `loop`/`recur` but you risk exhausting stack space. You could also think about doing this with `reduce`.

Comment: Oh,I really forgot about the map function, thanks :D By the way it'd be great if I had a version using recursion, just to let me see where I made the mistake

Comment: @MártonKardos map, reduce, filter,  apply    are the swiss army knife of FP

Answer (score 0):

Let's prepare a file:

```
(spit "foo.txt" "  3 5  662 35 3  ")
```

Now let's read the file, split the string by empty symbols, remove empty ones and parse them into integers. The code

```
(as->
   "foo.txt" $ 
   (slurp $)
   (clojure.string/split $ #"\s+")
   (remove empty? $)
   (mapv #(java.lang.Integer/parseInt %) $))
```

gives

```
[3 5 662 35 3]
```